# Obtaining Dutch citizenship

Tags: citizenship, netherlands

My mother's maiden name was Baroness Van Heerdt and her father was Baron Van Heerdt, but her mother was English. Coming from a line of Dutch nobility on my mothers side, would I be eligible for an EU passport?

Comment: Welcome to Expatriates. What research on the topic have you done so far? For example, a quick internet search revealed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_nationality_law

Comment: It depends on your grandparents' nationality, the circumstances and date of their marriage, the date of your mother's birth, the date of her marriage to your father (and of her other marriages, if there were any before you reached the age of majority), on where your grandfather and mother lived (and why), on your date of birth and (depending on your age) on where you've lived.  It also depends on whether your mother or her parents ever naturalized anywhere, and, if so, when.  When were you, your mother, and your grandfather born?

Comment: @Traveller that article is slightly out of date, but more importantly it doesn't describe the former state of the law in much detail, in particular the conditions for acquiring and retaining Dutch nationality before 1985.  These changed a few times between 1892 and 1985, but those changes are not mentioned.  Whether that is relevant here is not clear since we don't know the dates of any of the significant events.